# Write lines of text at a given position in a file in R

Tags: r, file

I would like to write a line in a text file at a given position (i) by avoiding the sequential reading.
There is WriteLines base function but I don't know how to insert the text at position (i) given as parameter.

Thanks

Dave

Comment: Why not use `readLines` to read the whole file producing a character vector of length equal to the number of lines; then insert a line at the required position, and use `writeLines` to write to file?

Comment: Agree but I want to avoid the sequential reading since my files a large.

Comment: What do you mean by "sequential reading"? You read the file once; insert, and write back to file.

Answer (score 2):

Here you are:

```r
add_lines = function(file = "file_path", ..., after) {
    lines <- readLines(file)
    to_add <- unlist(rlang::dots_list(...))
    lines <- append(lines, to_add, after = after)
    write(lines, file = file)
  }
fs::file_create("my_file.R")
write(paste("line", 1:3), "my_file.R")
add_lines("my_file.R", "Add this line", "And this line", after = 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is — unrelated to R — fundamentally impossible. Most (*all* common) filesystems do not support inserting or removing content in the middle of a file. The only supported operations are appending (or truncation) at the end, and R only supports appending, not truncation.

The way virtually all software solves your problem is by reading the file, modifying it, and writing it back to disk. If you want to get fancy because the file is very large (at least in the order of hundreds of MiB), you can stream edit the file: Read a part, edit that part, write it back to a new file. Rinse and repeat.

---

Technical aside: There is one exception to the above with low-level file operations, since files are stored as as *non-contiguous “blocks”*. But even if R supported this it wouldn’t help you since it doesn’t permit byte-level or line-level granularity: Blocks are typically at least 4 kiB in size.

Comment: @PoGibas I don't understand what the styler package has to do with the question, or with my answer.